# How can I space my triangle correctly?

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to print out a Right Triangle that looks like this:

```
                      1
                    2 1
                  3 2 1
              5 4 3 2 1
            6 5 4 3 2 1
          7 6 5 4 3 2 1
        8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
      9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
   10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

The size of the triangle increases if the number in the method gets larger, which in this case is 11. 
My code seems to only work up to 10 as after 10, my spacing is messed up.

`1
                        2 1
                      3 2 1
                    4 3 2 1
                  5 4 3 2 1
                6 5 4 3 2 1
              7 6 5 4 3 2 1
            8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
          9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
        10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
      11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
    12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1`

I am trying to make it so that up to 99, the spacing is correct. What kind of edits should I do to my if statements or for loops in order to space it properly?

Code:

```
public class Patterns 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    displayPattern(13);
    //displayPattern(11,",");
}
public static void displayPattern(int n)
{
    //print out n-1 spaces and the first number
    //print n-2 spaces and the 2nd then first number
    int counter = n;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
    {
        for(int j = 1; j <= counter; j++)
        {
            if (n > 10)
            {
                if (i == n)
                {
                    System.out.print("");
                }
                else if (i <= 10)
                {
                    System.out.print("  ");

                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print("  ");

                }

            }
            else if (n <=10)
            {
                if (i>9)
                {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print("  ");
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.print(i + " ");
        int tempValue = i - 1;
        while(tempValue>0)
        {
            System.out.print(tempValue);
            if(tempValue>1)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            tempValue--;
        }
        if(tempValue==0)
        {
            System.out.print("\n");

        }
        counter--;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why don't use a 2d String array?

Comment: Consider the last line: how many character positions will it take? Then for each line, how many leading spaces are needed to fill up the maximum line?